# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA224withRSA Signature not available Java 7

Tags: java, ssl

I have the Java environment Java 7 and I cannot upgrade the Java version to 8 as per our client's requirement.

I needed to connect a URL which supports TLSv1.2 therefore I have enabled `-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2`, `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<keystoreFilePath>` and `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<password>`

And I got below exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Error signing certificate verify
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1054)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:341)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:837)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1092)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA224withRSA Signature not available
at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:224)
at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getSignature(JsseJce.java:241)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateVerify.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:1552)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1049)
```

I have went through solutions given for the problem already faced, but all those required to upgrade to Java version (Of course I have checked all the Signatures provided by the Providers those don't contain SHA224withRSA signature).

For reference:

```
SUN version 1.7
    Alg.Alias.Signature.SHA1/DSA
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.2.840.10040.4.3
    Alg.Alias.Signature.DSS
    SecureRandom.SHA1PRNG ImplementedIn
    KeyStore.JKS
    Alg.Alias.MessageDigest.SHA-1
    MessageDigest.SHA
    KeyStore.CaseExactJKS
    CertStore.com.sun.security.IndexedCollection ImplementedIn
    Alg.Alias.Signature.DSA
    KeyFactory.DSA ImplementedIn
    KeyStore.JKS ImplementedIn
    AlgorithmParameters.DSA ImplementedIn
    Signature.NONEwithDSA
    Alg.Alias.CertificateFactory.X509
    CertStore.com.sun.security.IndexedCollection
    Provider.id className
    Alg.Alias.Signature.SHA-1/DSA
    CertificateFactory.X.509 ImplementedIn
    Signature.SHA1withDSA KeySize
    KeyFactory.DSA
    CertPathValidator.PKIX ImplementedIn
    Configuration.JavaLoginConfig
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.2.840.10040.4.3
    Alg.Alias.KeyFactory.1.2.840.10040.4.1
    MessageDigest.MD5 ImplementedIn
    Alg.Alias.Signature.RawDSA
    Provider.id name
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.1.2.840.10040.4.1
    CertPathBuilder.PKIX ValidationAlgorithm
    Policy.JavaPolicy
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.1.3.14.3.2.12
    Alg.Alias.Signature.SHA/DSA
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.1.3.14.3.2.12
    MessageDigest.SHA-384
    Signature.SHA1withDSA ImplementedIn
    AlgorithmParameterGenerator.DSA
    Signature.NONEwithDSA SupportedKeyClasses
    MessageDigest.SHA-512
    CertPathBuilder.PKIX
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.3.14.3.2.27
    CertPathBuilder.PKIX ImplementedIn
    Provider.id version
    AlgorithmParameters.DSA
    Signature.SHA1withDSA SupportedKeyClasses
    CertStore.Collection
    AlgorithmParameterGenerator.DSA ImplementedIn
    KeyPairGenerator.DSA KeySize
    CertStore.LDAP
    CertificateFactory.X.509
    SecureRandom.NativePRNG
    CertStore.LDAP LDAPSchema
    CertStore.LDAP ImplementedIn
    KeyPairGenerator.DSA ImplementedIn
    CertPathValidator.PKIX ValidationAlgorithm
    CertStore.Collection ImplementedIn
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.3.14.3.2.13
    CertPathValidator.PKIX
    Alg.Alias.MessageDigest.SHA1
    AlgorithmParameterGenerator.DSA KeySize
    SecureRandom.SHA1PRNG
    Signature.SHA1withDSA
    Alg.Alias.KeyFactory.1.3.14.3.2.12
    KeyPairGenerator.DSA
    MessageDigest.SHA ImplementedIn
    Provider.id info
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.1.2.840.10040.4.1
    Alg.Alias.Signature.SHAwithDSA
    MessageDigest.MD5
    Alg.Alias.Signature.DSAWithSHA1
    MessageDigest.SHA-256
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.OID.1.2.840.10040.4.1
    MessageDigest.MD2
SunRsaSign version 1.7
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2
    Alg.Alias.KeyFactory.1.2.840.113549.1.1
    Signature.SHA512withRSA SupportedKeyClasses
    Provider.id version
    Signature.MD5withRSA SupportedKeyClasses
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.2.840.113549.1.1.13
    KeyPairGenerator.RSA
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.2.840.113549.1.1.12
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
    KeyFactory.RSA
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.3.14.3.2.29
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1
    Signature.MD2withRSA
    Signature.SHA384withRSA
    Signature.MD5withRSA
    Provider.id info
    Signature.SHA1withRSA SupportedKeyClasses
    Signature.SHA1withRSA
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
    Signature.SHA256withRSA
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4
    Provider.id className
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.13
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.12
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.11
    Signature.MD2withRSA SupportedKeyClasses
    Provider.id name
    Alg.Alias.KeyFactory.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1
    Signature.SHA384withRSA SupportedKeyClasses
    Signature.SHA512withRSA
    Signature.SHA256withRSA SupportedKeyClasses
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.1.2.840.113549.1.1
SunEC version 1.7
    KeyFactory.EC
    Signature.SHA1withECDSA ImplementedIn
    Provider.id version
    KeyPairGenerator.EC ImplementedIn
    Signature.SHA1withECDSA SupportedKeyClasses
    AlgorithmParameters.EC
    Signature.SHA512withECDSA SupportedKeyClasses
    KeyAgreement.ECDH
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.EllipticCurve
    KeyAgreement.ECDH ImplementedIn
    Signature.NONEwithECDSA SupportedKeyClasses
    Signature.SHA256withECDSA
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.EllipticCurve
    KeyPairGenerator.EC
    AlgorithmParameters.EC SupportedCurves
    Signature.SHA512withECDSA ImplementedIn
    Signature.SHA384withECDSA SupportedKeyClasses
    Signature.NONEwithECDSA
    Provider.id info
    Signature.SHA512withECDSA
    Alg.Alias.KeyFactory.EllipticCurve
    AlgorithmParameters.EC ImplementedIn
    Signature.NONEwithECDSA ImplementedIn
    Provider.id className
    Signature.SHA384withECDSA ImplementedIn
    KeyFactory.EC ImplementedIn
    Signature.SHA256withECDSA ImplementedIn
    AlgorithmParameters.EC KeySize
    KeyPairGenerator.EC KeySize
    Provider.id name
    Signature.SHA256withECDSA SupportedKeyClasses
    Signature.SHA1withECDSA
    Signature.SHA384withECDSA
    KeyAgreement.ECDH SupportedKeyClasses
    Signature.SHA1withECDSA KeySize
SunJSSE version 1.7
    Signature.MD5andSHA1withRSA
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2
    Alg.Alias.KeyManagerFactory.PKIX
    Provider.id name
    KeyManagerFactory.NewSunX509
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.3.14.3.2.29
    Signature.MD2withRSA
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1
    Provider.id version
    KeyManagerFactory.SunX509
    KeyFactory.RSA
    TrustManagerFactory.SunX509
    Alg.Alias.TrustManagerFactory.X.509
    SSLContext.TLSv1.2
    SSLContext.TLSv1.1
    Signature.MD5withRSA
    Alg.Alias.SSLContext.SSLv3
    Alg.Alias.SSLContext.SSL
    KeyStore.PKCS12
    Alg.Alias.TrustManagerFactory.SunPKIX
    Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLS
    Alg.Alias.KeyFactory.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1
    SSLContext.Default
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.1.2.840.113549.1.1
    Provider.id info
    Signature.SHA1withRSA
    TrustManagerFactory.PKIX
    SSLContext.TLSv1
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.3.14.3.2.29
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
    Alg.Alias.TrustManagerFactory.X509
    Provider.id className
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4
    Alg.Alias.KeyFactory.1.2.840.113549.1.1
    Alg.Alias.Signature.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2
    KeyPairGenerator.RSA
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
    Alg.Alias.Signature.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4
SunJCE version 1.7
    Cipher.Blowfish SupportedKeyFormats
    AlgorithmParameters.DESede
    AlgorithmParameters.DES
    Cipher.DES SupportedPaddings
    AlgorithmParameters.Blowfish
    Cipher.DESedeWrap SupportedKeyFormats
    Alg.Alias.KeyAgreement.1.2.840.113549.1.3.1
    AlgorithmParameterGenerator.DiffieHellman
    Cipher.RSA SupportedPaddings
    Alg.Alias.Cipher.TripleDES
    Cipher.ARCFOUR SupportedModes
    Mac.SslMacSHA1 SupportedKeyFormats
    KeyGenerator.DES
    Provider.id version
    KeyGenerator.DESede
    Alg.Alias.SecretKeyFactory.PBE
    Alg.Alias.KeyFactory.1.2.840.113549.1.3.1
    Mac.HmacSHA1
    Cipher.PBEWithMD5AndDES
    Cipher.AES SupportedModes
    Cipher.AESWrap SupportedModes
    SecretKeyFactory.DESede
    KeyGenerator.SunTlsKeyMaterial
    AlgorithmParameters.OAEP
    Cipher.AES SupportedKeyFormats
    AlgorithmParameters.RC2
    AlgorithmParameters.PBE
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.DH
    Alg.Alias.KeyAgreement.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.3.1
    Cipher.AES
    KeyGenerator.RC2
    Mac.HmacSHA512
    Provider.id info
    Cipher.AES SupportedPaddings
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.6
    Cipher.Blowfish SupportedPaddings
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3
    Alg.Alias.KeyGenerator.SunTls12KeyMaterial
    KeyStore.JCEKS
    Cipher.Blowfish SupportedModes
    Alg.Alias.SecretKeyFactory.1.2.840.113549.1.5.12
    Mac.HmacSHA384 SupportedKeyFormats
    Cipher.DESedeWrap
    Cipher.ARCFOUR SupportedPaddings
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.1.2.840.113549.1.3.1
    Cipher.PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES
    Alg.Alias.Cipher.1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.6
    Alg.Alias.Cipher.1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3
    Mac.HmacSHA256 SupportedKeyFormats
    Alg.Alias.KeyGenerator.SunTls12RsaPremasterSecret
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameterGenerator.1.2.840.113549.1.3.1
    Cipher.PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
    Alg.Alias.KeyGenerator.SunTls12MasterSecret
    SecretKeyFactory.PBEWithMD5AndDES
    KeyPairGenerator.DiffieHellman
    Cipher.RC2 SupportedModes
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.Rijndael
    KeyAgreement.DiffieHellman SupportedKeyClasses
    Mac.HmacMD5 SupportedKeyFormats
    KeyGenerator.SunTlsRsaPremasterSecret
    Cipher.AESWrap SupportedKeyFormats
    SecretKeyFactory.DES
    Cipher.AESWrap SupportedPaddings
    Provider.id name
    KeyGenerator.HmacSHA512
    Mac.HmacSHA256
    Cipher.ARCFOUR SupportedKeyFormats
    Cipher.DES SupportedModes
    Cipher.RSA SupportedKeyClasses
    SecretKeyFactory.PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES
    Cipher.PBEWithSHA1AndRC2_40
    AlgorithmParameters.DiffieHellman
    Mac.HmacMD5
    Cipher.RSA
    Mac.SslMacMD5
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.5.3
    Cipher.DESede SupportedPaddings
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameterGenerator.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.3.1
    Cipher.DESede
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.3.1
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.1.2.840.113549.1.5.3
    Mac.HmacSHA512 SupportedKeyFormats
    Mac.HmacPBESHA1 SupportedKeyFormats
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameterGenerator.DH
    Cipher.DESedeWrap SupportedPaddings
    Alg.Alias.SecretKeyFactory.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.5.12
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.1.2.840.113549.1.3.1
    Mac.HmacPBESHA1
    Cipher.DES SupportedKeyFormats
    AlgorithmParameters.PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES
    Cipher.DESedeWrap SupportedModes
    Alg.Alias.KeyFactory.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.3.1
    Alg.Alias.Cipher.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.5.3
    AlgorithmParameters.AES
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.TripleDES
    Alg.Alias.SecretKeyFactory.TripleDES
    KeyGenerator.HmacSHA256
    Alg.Alias.KeyGenerator.TripleDES
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.DH
    KeyGenerator.AES
    Cipher.RC2 SupportedPaddings
    Alg.Alias.Cipher.RC4
    Alg.Alias.KeyPairGenerator.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.3.1
    Mac.HmacSHA384
    SecretKeyFactory.PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1
    Provider.id className
    Cipher.DES
    Cipher.Blowfish
    KeyGenerator.SunTlsMasterSecret
    KeyGenerator.HmacSHA1
    Alg.Alias.SecretKeyFactory.1.2.840.113549.1.5.3
    KeyGenerator.SunTlsPrf
    SecretKeyFactory.PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
    KeyGenerator.ARCFOUR
    Alg.Alias.KeyAgreement.DH
    Alg.Alias.KeyGenerator.Rijndael
    AlgorithmParameters.PBEWithSHA1AndDESede
    Alg.Alias.KeyGenerator.RC4
    Alg.Alias.Cipher.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.6
    Alg.Alias.Cipher.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3
    Mac.SslMacMD5 SupportedKeyFormats
    Mac.HmacSHA1 SupportedKeyFormats
    Cipher.DESede SupportedKeyFormats
    Cipher.RC2
    KeyGenerator.SunTls12Prf
    SecretKeyFactory.PBEWithSHA1AndRC2_40
    KeyGenerator.HmacMD5
    AlgorithmParameters.PBEWithSHA1AndRC2_40
    KeyGenerator.HmacSHA384
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.6
    KeyFactory.DiffieHellman
    Alg.Alias.AlgorithmParameters.1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3
    AlgorithmParameters.PBEWithMD5AndDES
    Alg.Alias.SecretKeyFactory.1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.6
    Alg.Alias.SecretKeyFactory.1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3
    Cipher.AESWrap
    Alg.Alias.SecretKeyFactory.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.5.3
    Alg.Alias.Cipher.Rijndael
    Cipher.RSA SupportedModes
    Cipher.DESede SupportedModes
    Alg.Alias.SecretKeyFactory.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.6
    Alg.Alias.SecretKeyFactory.OID.1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.3
    Cipher.ARCFOUR
    Alg.Alias.Cipher.1.2.840.113549.1.5.3
    Mac.SslMacSHA1
    KeyAgreement.DiffieHellman
    Cipher.RC2 SupportedKeyFormats
    Alg.Alias.KeyFactory.DH
    KeyGenerator.Blowfish
SunJGSS version 1.7
    GssApiMechanism.1.3.6.1.5.5.2
    Provider.id info
    Provider.id className
    Provider.id version
    GssApiMechanism.1.2.840.113554.1.2.2
    Provider.id name
SunSASL version 1.7
    SaslClientFactory.NTLM
    Provider.id className
    SaslClientFactory.CRAM-MD5
    Provider.id version
    SaslClientFactory.EXTERNAL
    SaslClientFactory.PLAIN
    SaslClientFactory.DIGEST-MD5
    SaslServerFactory.NTLM
    Provider.id name
    SaslClientFactory.GSSAPI
    SaslServerFactory.DIGEST-MD5
    SaslServerFactory.CRAM-MD5
    SaslServerFactory.GSSAPI
    Provider.id info
XMLDSig version 1.0
    Alg.Alias.TransformService.ENVELOPED
    Alg.Alias.TransformService.XSLT
    Provider.id name
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11#WithComments
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116 MechanismType
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments MechanismType
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#base64 MechanismType
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2 MechanismType
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n# MechanismType
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116 MechanismType
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments MechanismType
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315
    Provider.id version
    KeyInfoFactory.DOM
    Alg.Alias.TransformService.XPATH
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature
    Alg.Alias.TransformService.BASE64
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11 MechanismType
    Alg.Alias.TransformService.EXCLUSIVE_WITH_COMMENTS
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315 MechanismType
    Provider.id info
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments
    Alg.Alias.TransformService.INCLUSIVE
    Alg.Alias.TransformService.XPATH2
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature MechanismType
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116
    Alg.Alias.TransformService.EXCLUSIVE
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2006/12/xml-c14n11#WithComments MechanismType
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#base64
    XMLSignatureFactory.DOM
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2002/06/xmldsig-filter2
    Provider.id className
    TransformService.http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#WithComments
    Alg.Alias.TransformService.INCLUSIVE_WITH_COMMENTS
SunPCSC version 1.7
    Provider.id info
    Provider.id className
    Provider.id version
    Provider.id name
    TerminalFactory.PC/SC
```

But I cannot upgrade to Java 8 since the client's requirement is not to upgrade to Java 8.

Please provide a solution without upgrading to Java 8. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you installed the *Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7*. Some crypto algorithms (especially those with large key size) are by default disabled and can be enabled by installing these policy files.

Comment: Hi @Robert, Still I get the same issue even after I installed the policy files

Comment: According to [JEP130](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/130) SHA224 support was added in Java 8. May be you can install a 3rd party JCE library that includes SHA224 support?

Comment: Hi @Robert, Still I face the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I've checked the algorithms supported by java versions(1.7) & (1.8) in my machine. One of my project runs on jdk 1.7.0_80, which doesn't support SHA224withRSA algorithm, if you're in same situation then upgrade to newer version of java atleast to (Java SE 7 Update 131)as I've read it should have similar algorithms as java 8. If no option to update java then try adding **org.bouncycastle** **bcprov-jdk15on** maven dependency in pom or a jar file to your project & also in java code add where you build SSLContext/HttpClient include below line:

> Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

Also tried installing Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 7, but it hasn't worked for me !!

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same problem , but i got solution . jdk 1.7.0_80, which doesn't support SHA224withRSA algorithm. so we have to use 3rd party vendors for include that signature we can use JCE, open jdk, etc.
I use open JDK 7 for solve this issue.
please go to this url https://www.azul.com/downloads/?architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk Scroll down and search for 7u312b01 .
[image]

then click on .zip and after download extract it and in eclipse right click on project-> Run as -> run configuration -> JRE tab-> Alternate JRE (radio button) -> install-> add -> standard vm-> next-> Directory -> search location of open jdk7 (zulu7.48.0.11-ca-jdk7.0.312-win_x64) select folder-> finish -> apply and close->

[image]

click on run and see magic... console will show  SHA224withRSA. when you run these code

```
TreeSet<String> algorithms = new TreeSet<>();
    for (Provider provider : Security.getProviders())
        for (Service service : provider.getServices())
            if (service.getType().equals("Signature"))
                algorithms.add(service.getAlgorithm());
    for (String algorithm : algorithms)
        System.out.println(algorithm);
```

[image]

for more details please visit https://techoral.com/blog/java/how-to-download-and-install-openjdk-7-on-windows.html

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4172681/where-we-can-download-jdk1-7-0-191

Answer (score 0):

**If someone has problems with JAVA 8 + SHA224.**

After migrated to Java 8 (v101), I faced same error because my application use private key in SunMSCAPI and SHA224 at the same time. Looking for answers I've figure out that downgrading to version 8.0.51 solved it (could work in another versions less than 100).

Reason: they removed SHA224 from default providers when SunMSCAPI is enabled.
Source: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8064330