# JVM picks latest https protocols among enabled protocols?

Tags: java, ssl

Through JBOSS server, I need to connect multiple URLs which supports different https.protocols.

Say for example,
I need to connect X which support `TLSv1, TLSv1.1` and `TLSv1.2` but Java 7 doesn't support some signature when use `TLSv1.2` so I wanted to use `TLSv1` or `TLSv1.1`,
Need to connect Y which support `TLSv1`, 
Need to connect Z which support `TLSv1.2`

Therefore I enabled multiple https protocols in JVM to connect all X,Y, and Z:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

But when I tried to connect X, it always picks `TLSv1.2`. So I get error:

```
SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
```

Assume that I use different 3 Java classes to implement the connection for X,Y and Y. And at a time these classes can be accessed by multiple threads (say 10000 threads).

How can I enable those protocols for each classes?

- Class for X - TLSv1.1
- Class for Y - TLSv1
- Class for Z - TLSv1.2

I feel it is not good idea to put like this (since multiple threads access here and there) :
say for example - X - `System.getProperties().setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.1");`

Please provide a proper solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When a server that supports only TLSv1.1 receives a TLSv1.2 request it should just use TLSv1.1 in the response. If it is acting differently the server may be defect and it may be worth further debugging to find out what exactly is the problem.

Comment: hi @Robert, I have already debug and the actual problem is this (already added this question) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43208468/java-security-nosuchalgorithmexception-sha224withrsa-signature-not-available-ja . Some how I found that for X, through Java 7, I could be able to connect with TLSv1. But if I do the changes for X, other 2 will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are calling X, Y and Z from your code? In that case you should be able to use a custom SSLContextFactory configured the way you want for the respective calls. Then you don't need the system properties. If you are using the built-in HttpsUrlConnection it has a setSSLSocketFactory method that works per instance rather than globally. Other popular HTTP clients have similar features.

Edit: example that seems to work with X and Z, see comments below.

```
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(tlsVersion);
    sslContext.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());
    conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    try (InputStream is = conn.getInputStream()) {
      // Read response
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this before I post this question. It didn't work.

Comment: Are X, Y and Z public so that we can test, or are they internal sites? I guess they are internal as you kept them secret, but it is worth asking.

Comment: Nope, they are not. All are third party sites

Comment: Then perhaps you can spell them out so that we can test?

Comment: Hi, Say X = netfundstest.com , Y = some other domain which supports TLSv1 , Z = siteminder.atlassian.net